# Read javascript from pdf using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, javascript, pdf, itext

I have a script that runs after the pdf-file has been loaded and that populates some form fields in the pdf. I assume it is some kind of javascript running behind the scene. In the javascript code some values are stored that I need to retrieve. I use iTextSharp to work with the pdf-file. Is it possible to read the javascript code or the values so I can work with them in my c# code somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified from this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409278/remove-javascript-from-pdf-using-itextsharp):

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(infilename);
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, memoryStream);
    for (int i = 0; i <= pdfReader.XrefSize; i++)
    {
        PdfDictionary pd = pdfReader.GetPdfObject(i) as PdfDictionary;
        if (pd != null)
        {
            PdfObject poAA = pd.Get(PdfName.AA); //Gets automatic execution objects
            PdfObject poJS = pd.Get(PdfName.JS); // Gets javascript objects
            PdfObject poJavaScript = pd.Get(PdfName.JAVASCRIPT); // Gets other javascript objects
            //use poJS.GetBytes(), poJS.ToString() etc to inspect details...
        }
    }
    stamper.Close();
    pdfReader.Close();
    File.WriteAllBytes(rawfile, memoryStream.ToArray());
}
```

Here's a reference page for the PdfObject [class](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs-itextsharp/html/a5096b65-4761-594b-82e2-7cec7adcfecf.htm).

Comment: Thanks! This works although I found no values. I think it might be in a fdf file. But I have no idea where in the pdf file the path to the fdf file is stored and how to access it? The answer is correct so I will mark it as an answer but it seems it's not the answer I need :)

Comment: @Janspeed can you post the pdf for inspection?