# Extract masks from text fields using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

How can I extract masks from textfields in a form using iTextSharp?
For instance, I know that there is a "Date" field that required the format to be like dd/mm/yyyy. Where this data is stored?

thanks

Comment: AcroForm technology doesn't provide the means to store a mask (check ISO-32000-1: you won't find any reference to such a thing). The ISO committee has composed an adhoc team to provide this, but the work on such a feature will start only after ISO-32000-2 is released, hence it's not something you should expect for the near future. However, several PDFs have Javascript attached to a text field that are used to format its contents, e.g. to force people to enter a certain pattern. There are many different ways to write such a script. You won't find a uniform "mask".

Comment: I'm with Bruno, you'll need to basically write a JavaScript parser. However, if all of your PDFs are created from a single application (such as Adobe Acrobat) you might find a consistent pattern that you can regex. See this answer for getting to the [JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20244486/231316).

Comment: Thank you guys. I noticed that the form I was trying to extract the information was in XFA format so this "format"/mask information is actually embedded in file.